# Coordinator layout with viewpager with recyclerview as adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, coordinator-layout

I have this layout with coordinator layout, that has tabs with viewpager and in viewpager adapter I create recyclerview for each page.

Layout :

```
08-09 11:28:17.816    2804-2804/com.xxx.yyy.debug     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:638)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.ensureExpandedTexture(CollapsingTextHelper.java:413)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setInterpolatedTextSize(CollapsingTextHelper.java:390)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.calculateOffsets(CollapsingTextHelper.java:227)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setExpansionFraction(CollapsingTextHelper.java:203)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout$OffsetUpdateListener.onOffsetChanged(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:768)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.dispatchOffsetUpdates(AppBarLayout.java:853)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.setAppBarTopBottomOffset(AppBarLayout.java:836)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.scroll(AppBarLayout.java:795)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onNestedPreScroll(AppBarLayout.java:635)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onNestedPreScroll(AppBarLayout.java:583)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout.java:1477)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewParentCompat$ViewParentCompatStubImpl.onNestedPreScroll(ViewParentCompat.java:106)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewParentCompat.onNestedPreScroll(ViewParentCompat.java:355)
        at android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(NestedScrollingChildHelper.java:208)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchNestedPreScroll(RecyclerView.java:8376)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2191)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7205)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2231)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2151)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1480)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2435)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2099)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7385)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3398
```

Here are the layouts :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/turquoise_blue"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
            layout="@layout/profile_content" />

    <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the profile content layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ui.screen.ProfileView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/profile_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_appbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:elevation="2dp"
                >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:elevation="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/profile_user_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="192dp"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:clipChildren="false"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                        android:paddingRight="24dp"
                        android:paddingTop="64dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:clipChildren="false"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="96dp"
                                android:layout_height="96dp"
                                android:clipChildren="false">

                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_photo"
                                    android:layout_width="86dp"
                                    android:layout_height="86dp"
                                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                                    app:border_width="1dp"
                                    app:border_color="@color/white"/>

                            <View
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_medal"
                                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/medal"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"/>

                        </FrameLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/profile_user_details"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

                            <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_name"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Kateřina Bíla"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="24sp"/>

                            <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_completed_activities"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Dokoncene 4 z 5"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                            <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/profile_user_progress_text"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textSize="20sp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        android:text="50%"/>

                                <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
                                        android:id="@+id/profile_user_progress_bar"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="6dp"
                                        android:visibility="visible"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                        app:pv_progressMode="determinate"
                                        app:pv_circular="false"
                                        app:pv_autostart="true"
                                        app:lpd_strokeSize="3dp"
                                        app:lpd_strokeColor="@color/red"
                                        app:lpd_strokeSecondaryColor="@color/white"
                                        app:lpd_maxLineWidth="62dp"
                                        app:lpd_minLineWidth="31dp"
                                        app:pv_progressStyle="@style/ProfileTotalProgressBar"
                                        app:pv_progress="0.5"/>


                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <include
                    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/profile_tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/white_87"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
                />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</ui.screen.ProfileView>
```

The thing is this only happens on Samsung S3 mini. I tried more devices like Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S6, some older HTC devices, but only on the mini I get this error while trying to scroll up with recyclerview. I don't get the bitmap error.

Edit: I made some more research, this problem seems to be affecting all devices on API lower than KitKat.

Comment: wich version of libraries did you use? update them to v22.0.1. many bugs have been fixed in this version.

Comment: @SinaKH com.android.support:design:22.2.1

Comment: exactly i meant 22.2.1 ,, I don't know, please don't forget to send answer here if you found it, tnx :)

Comment: sure will for now I created separated layouts for api levels

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today.

I finally managed to solve it. In my case it was because
i got textSize **0sp** to make text invisible in expanded mode:

`<style name="AdDetailExpandedTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
</style>`

I set the textSize to something other than 0sp, instead set color #00000000 to make it transparent.